# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_create_nonce()

Tags: nonce

I'm trying to add a nonce to my plugin's Ajax. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_create_nonce()

In my php file :

```
wp_localize_script('my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array('ajaxurl'=> admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'my_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('myajax-nonce')));
```

In js file:

```
jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, {my_nonce : the_ajax_script.my_nonce}, jQuery("#theForm").serialize() + "&maxLat="+ map_bounds[0] + "&maxLong="+ map_bounds[1] + "&minLat="+ map_bounds[2] + "&minLong="+ map_bounds[3],
    function(response_from_the_action_function){
       jQuery("#response_area").html(response_from_the_action_function);
    });
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More context would be helpful.  Is that all the code found in your plugin or functions file directly? Or are you hooking in to something via `add_action`.

Anyway, what's probably wrong is that you're calling `wp_localize_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` outside of an action.  `wp_create_nonce`, or, rather, the file in which it resides, has yet to be loaded.

The solution is to call `wp_localize_script` from inside a function hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts`

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse30583_enqueue' );
function wpse30583_enqueue()
{
    // your enqueue will probably look different.
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse30583_script' );

    // Localize the script
    $data = array( 
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'wpse30583_nonce' )
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'wpse30583_script', 'wpse3058_object', $data );
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Christopher Davis, Thank you very much for your message. You're right, I didn't have wp_localize_script inside a function. I never would have thought of your solution. I plopped it in a function and now I don't get the fatal error anymore. Unfortunately, I must have a second bug. I don't think that the nonce is being posted. Does this bit look correct: jQuery.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, {my_nonce : the_ajax_script.my_nonce}, jQuery("#theForm").serialize()... Also, I tried putting an echo in php and alert on the js. It looks like the 2 numbers are different. Is this normal? Thank you.

Comment: Better ask that in a separate question.  Maybe someone else has had a similar issue.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that. I'll go ahead and post a new one. Thank you very much for the help!